# I have an activity in a project but when activity start i have node in firebase it should be online but its not working?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

if I minimize my app and run that activity it works but when I come to that activity from another activity its not working.

In my onCreate like below

```
auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = auth.getCurrentUser();

        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        userRef = db.getReference().child("Users").child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

        if(currentUser == null) {
            sendToStart();
        } else {
            userRef.child("online").setValue("true");
        }
```

I have the same thing in my onStart method too but not working.
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should try updating its node by execution of this statement in background service.

```
public class MyService extends Service {

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      //TODO do something useful

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUser = auth.getCurrentUser();

    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    userRef = db.getReference().child("Users").child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

    if(currentUser == null) {
        sendToStart();
    } else {
        userRef.child("online").setValue("true");
    }


      return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    //TODO for communication return IBinder implementation
    return null;
  }
}


Intent i= new Intent(context, MyService.class);
context.startService(i);
```

Comment: how can i do that

Comment: check answer i have added.